# SQL - Select preferred version

Tags: sql, select, row, version

I have a speed table with a version field. Here is a partial sample :

```
     id    milepost  speed version

     1           0     40       1
     2           0     30       2
     3           5     50       1
```

Basically, I want to do a query with a "preferred version" : try to fetch rows (mileposts) with the specified speed version, and if a certain milepost is not found with that version, take version 1 by default.
So, for example, if my preferred speed version was 2, my result would contain speeds from rows 2 and 3 :

```
   milepost  speed

          0     30
          5     50
```

But how can I build a single SELECT to do that ?
Thank you, and have a nice stack overday.

EDIT : 
Both of your answers have inspired me to find a solution. The following is not the complete query, but it gives an idea :

```
select s1.milepost_from milepost, s1.value speed from speeds s1
where s1.version = 2 or (s1.version = 1 and not exists
(select 1 from speeds s2 where s2.milepost_from = s1.milepost_from and s2.version = 2))
```

The key is to do a subselect that matches the main select's permanent info (milepost_from in the example).
Thank you !

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you're talking about which SQL type I'm using, I am using the dbaccess tool of Informix SQL.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `union all`:

```
select t.*
from t
where version = @preferred_version
union all
select t.*
from t
where version = 1 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.version = @preferred_version and t2.id = t.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left joins and coalesce

```
SELECT IDLIST.ID AS ID, COALESCE(T1.SPEED, T2.SPEED, <final default value>) AS SPEED
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE) AS IDLIST
LEFT JOIN TABLE T1 ON IDLIST.ID = T1.ID AND T2.VERSION = <ver you look for>
LEFT JOIN TABLE T2 ON IDLIST.ID = T2.ID AND T2.VERSION = <default marker>
```

As you can see this lets you have multiple "defaults" so it is more general.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of the COALESCE function in Informix Sql ?

Comment: NVL() - http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_151.htm